# Google bot causes exceptions in my Tapestry app

Tags: exception, tapestry, googlebot

Google bot is causing a lot of errors in my tapestry 5 application. For example, recently I have changed component id from 'select' to something else. Since that I have a lot of errors in logs (see below), but for users everything is working fine.

I'm not able to get rid off this. I have tried to play with caching, XHR request etc. Nothing seems to work. Could you please help me with this issue? Have i overlooked something? Thank you in advance.

```
30.11.2013 08:53:14 79499699 [TP-Processor16] ERROR TapestryModule.RequestExceptionHandler  - Processing of request failed with uncaught exception: Component profile/View:companycard.broadnavigation does not contain embedded component 'select'.
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.util.UnknownValueException: Component profile/View:companycard.broadnavigation does not contain embedded component 'select'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to formulate a `robots.txt` to tell googlebot not to follow your ajax URL's. Since all ajax URL's contain a `:` character, you might be able to do something like:

robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: \*:*
```

I'm not sure there's common pattern for submit URL's. I think it will be harder to tell googlebot to ignore submit URL's.

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak tapestry's exception reporting to fail silently for googlebot and other crawlers. You can test for most bots by injecting the `Request` and checking the `User-Agent` header.

- http://tapestry.apache.org/overriding-exception-reporting.html
- http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/bots
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I think, your solution is solving consequences, not a reason. I will try few more things and I'll see. May be I really end up with your solution. :)

Comment: Googlebot will often make invalid requests to tapestry. It will sometimes hit a submit url with a GET when tapestry requires a POST. And other times it will hit URL's without passing the required request parameters etc that are proided when a user is clicking links on your site. Do you know which URL googlebot was hitting? Perhaps add some logging for next time if not.